# Splunk Query to find greater than

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a splunk log
LOG: `"TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:0"`

I need to Query it in a way that it find a log message if the number of records turn out to be more than 0

I have tried the following

```
 sourcetype=mylogs | rex "\d+:\d+:\d+\s(?<TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:>\d+)$" | where TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:>=25
```

It gives a terminator Error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with that query.

- The regular expression looks for 3 sets of digits separated by colons.  That doesn't match your example.  Try `TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:(?<field>\d+)`.  You may even get by with `:(?<field>\d+)`.
- The field name in your query should not have spaces in it.  Try something like `TotalNumberOfRecords`.
- Field names can't contain colons.  That's probably the source of the error message.

Try this query:
`sourcetype=mylogs | rex ":\d+(?<TotalNumberOfRecords>\d+)" | where TotalNumberOfRecords>=25`

Answer (score 2):

This did not work for me, may be different splunk versions.
I wanted to get "An event at a delay of 102" log for values greater than 100.

Below query worked.

```
index="***" sourcetype="***" "An event" | rex "An event at a delay of (?<delay>[0-9]+)" | where delay > 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example SPL to suit your requirement:

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:10"
| rex field=_raw "TOTAL NUMBER OF RECORDS IS:(?<record_num>.\d+)" 
| where record_num > 0
```

**Line-by-line Explanation:**

1. Line 1-2: Creating a dummy event for this test.
2. Line 3: Extract the value of number of records from `_raw` and store it in `record_num` field.
3. Line 4: `where` clause to filter results.